# Storing a VBA Range in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to define a dynamic range in VBA for some operations I have to do with a matrix, as follows:

```
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
'...
'define some indexes
'...
Set Range1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(rowFirst, colFirst), Cells(rowEnd,colEnd))
```

But I'm getting the runtime error #1004, and I don't know why and how to fix it.

I'm new to VBA so I was expecting you could help me.

Thanks to all!

**Note**: The `rowFirst,colFirst,rowEnd,colEnd` variables are constantly changing since I need to be moving in the worksheet from matrix to matrix.

## Edit

Thank you all for your responses, *but I'm still getting the same error on the same line*.
Let me explain a little bit deeper what's what I'm trying to do. I need to take a 13x91(in cells) matrix and transpose it, then I need to join all in one single column, and put the resultant column in the Sheet 2. This done 20 times advancing in columns (and not in rows). Here I leave the code:

```
    Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
        Dim it As Integer
        Dim rowInit As Integer, rowEnd As Integer, colInit As Integer, colEnd As Integer
        rowInit = 1
        rowEnd = 91
        colInit = 1
        colInit = 13
        For it = 1 To 20
            Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
            Dim rowIndex As Integer
            xTitleId = "Automatización"
            Set Range1 = Hoja1.Range(Hoja1.Cells(rowInit, colInit), Hoja1.Cells(rowEnd, colEnd))
            Set Range2 = Sheets("Hoja2").Range(Cells(1, it))
            colInit = colInit + 13
            colEnd = colEnd + 13
            rowIndex = 0
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
                Rng.Copy
                Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
                rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
            Next
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Next it
    End Sub
```

**Note 2:** Since I work in Excel in Spanish, the `Hoja1` object means `Sheet1`

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowFirst, colFirst), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowEnd,colEnd))` Assign Parentage to ALL range objects.

Comment: Tried but didn't work, check out my edit. And thanks!

Comment: `Hoja1` should be `Worksheets("Hoja1")`

Comment: Still getting error 1004, what else could it be?

Comment: see my answer below.  you had other things wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your new code three things:

1. `Hoja1` should be `Worksheets("Hoja1")`
2. You never assigned value to `colEnd` but had `colInit` twice.
3. you cannot put one `Cells()` inside a `Range()`.  Just use the `Cells()` by itself.

code:

```
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
    Dim it As Integer
    Dim rowInit As Integer, rowEnd As Integer, colInit As Integer, colEnd As Integer
    rowInit = 1
    rowEnd = 91
    colInit = 1
    colEnd = 13
    For it = 1 To 20
        Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
        Dim rowIndex As Integer
        xTitleId = "Automatización"
        Set Range1 = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range(Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(rowInit, colInit), Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(rowEnd, colEnd))
        Set Range2 = Worksheets("Hoja2").Cells(1, it)
        colInit = colInit + 13
        colEnd = colEnd + 13
        rowIndex = 0
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
            Rng.Copy
            Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
            rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
        Next
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Next it
End Sub
```

Comment: Arguably row numbers should be `Long` integers, and there's still too much `Application.ScreenUpdating` toggling goign on (turning off should be before the outer loop, turning back on should be after `Next it` and before `End Sub`), but I don't see where this code could fail. Have an upvote!

Comment: @Mat'sMug arguably this code could go through a major rewrite to speed things up, but I will leave that to the OP to post on codereview for you wizards to tear apart.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottCraner, you're the best!

Comment: @sant016 IKR? He should totally be among the *wizards* that review and help improve working VBA code over at [codereview.se]! *did I write that out loud?*

Answer (score 1):

Try below code..cells should be referenced with the sheet.

```
       Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
       '...
      'define some indexes
         Set Range1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowFirst, colFirst), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowEnd,colEnd))
```

Comment: Although in the edit it's written different, I tried this option also and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `Sheets` function is implicitly referring to the `Sheets` collection of the `ActiveWorkbook`. You probably mean to use the `Worksheets` collection, which won't contain "chart sheets" and other non-worksheet objects.

Unqualified, `Range` implicitly refers to the `ActiveSheet`; same for an unqualified `Cells` call.

`Range(cell1, cell2)` *requires* that `cell1` and `cell2` are on the same sheet as whichever sheet object is qualifying the `Range` call - if `Range` is unqualified, then working off the active sheet will work.

But here `Range` is qualified with `Sheets("Sheet1")`, so `cell1` and `cell2` must *also* be on that same `Sheets("Sheet1")` worksheet, otherwise you get the error you're getting.

Also, if `Sheets("Sheet1")` is in `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook with the running VBA code), then you can refer to it by its global object (which you can rename in the *properties* toolwindow), using its *code name* - by default that would be `Sheet1` for, well, the "Sheet1" worksheet.

In other words:

```
Set Range1 = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(rowFirst, colFirst), Sheet1.Cells(rowEnd,colEnd))
Set Range2 = Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, it))
```

Comment: Tried this too and didn't work, check my edit please. And thanks.

Comment: You have the exact same problem on the `Set Range2` assignment too. I think Scott sorted it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1004 = This issue may occur if one or more of the cells in an array (range of cells) contain a character string that is set to contain more than 911 characters.

-> Does one of the values in your cells have more than 911 characters?